# Jackson Java EE WS - XML is empty but JSON has all fields

Tags: java, json, xml, web-services

I have a POJO that I'm exposing with a REST service:

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Field implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    @JsonIgnore
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    FieldType fieldType;

    String name;

    Object deafultValue;

    Map<String, String> choices;

    boolean required;

    public Field(){}

    @JsonCreator
    public Field(@JsonProperty("fieldType") FieldType fieldType, String name, Object deafultValue, Map<String, String> choices, boolean required) {
        super();
        this.fieldType = fieldType;
        this.name = name;
        this.deafultValue = deafultValue;
        this.choices = choices;
        this.required = required;
    }

    @JsonProperty 
    public FieldType getFieldType() {
        return fieldType;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Field [fieldType=" + fieldType + ", name=" + name + ", deafultValue=" + deafultValue + ", choices="
                + choices + ", required=" + required + "]";
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public Object getDeafultValue() {
        return deafultValue;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getChoices() {
        return choices;
    }

    public boolean isRequired() {
        return required;
    }

}
```

I have a number of objects that are exposed, but most of them are marked with the `@Entity` annotation and they work fine.

Here is my web service code:

```
@GET
    @Path("search-fields")
    @Produces({"application/xml", "application/json"})
    public List<Field> getSearchFields(){
        L.debug("Getting Actor search fields: {}", new Actor().getSearchFields());
        return new Actor().getSearchFields();
    }
```

The log message says that the data is there:

> > DEBUG ActorsFacadeREST - Getting Actor search fields: [Field [fieldType=INPUT, name=Name, deafultValue=null, choices=null, required=true]]

When I query for JSON:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/actor-service/webresources/entities.actors/search-fields/ && echo ""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 88
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:44:46 GMT

[{"fieldType":"INPUT","name":"Name","deafultValue":null,"choices":null,"required":true}]
```

When I ask for XML:

```
$ curl -i -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET http://localhost:8080/actor-service/webresources/entities.actors/search-fields/ && echo ""
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
X-Powered-By: Undertow/1
Server: WildFly/10
Content-Type: application/xml
Content-Length: 88
Date: Sun, 20 Mar 2016 13:46:47 GMT

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><collection><field/></collection>
```

Why does my JSON have the object data but the XML is empty?  Is there an XML annotation (I cannot find one) that I should be using other than `@XmlRootElement`?

**EDITED TO ADD**

I have the following bean that works properly:

```
public class Actor implements Serializable, HasImage, Searchable<Actor> {
    private static final transient Logger L = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Actor.class);
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long id;

    private String eid;

    private String name;

    private String status;

    private String reportsToEid;

    private String email;

    String imageLocation;


    PathType pathType;

    public Actor() {
        L.debug("Actor created with default constructor");
    }

    @JsonCreator
    public Actor(@JsonProperty("id") Long id, @JsonProperty("eid") String eid, @JsonProperty("name")String name, 
            @JsonProperty("status") String status, @JsonProperty("reportsToId") String reportsToEid, 
            @JsonProperty("email") String email, @JsonProperty("imageLocation")String imageLocation, 
            @JsonProperty("pathType") PathType pathType) {
        super();
        L.debug("Actor created with JsonCreator marked constructor");
        this.id = id;
        this.eid = eid;
        this.name = name;
        this.status = status;
        this.reportsToEid = reportsToEid;
        this.email = email;
        this.imageLocation = imageLocation;
        this.pathType = pathType;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to annotate your fields with @XmlElement as well...

Comment: OK, I posted a working object (in my edit above). Why doesn't it need them?